# SQL Error (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am trying to write a SELECT CASE expression to check a column to see if it is NULL. If it is not NULL, return the column. ELSE return "NA". I reference the correct table in FROM. Not sure why I am getting a conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error.

```
(
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DateCompleted IS NOT NULL THEN dbo.WF_InstanceSteps.DateCompleted
        ELSE ''NA''
    END AS DateCompleted
FROM
    dbo.WF_InstanceSteps
WHERE
    (StepId = 6) AND
    (InstanceId = dbo.WF_Instances.InstanceId)
) AS ApprovalDate
```

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as an empty string, nor the same as the string containing single quote characters - so your narrative doesn't seem to match your code. Also, why have you wrapped one of your references in double-quotes?

Comment: `AND (InstanceId = dbo.WF_Instances.InstanceId)` This confuses me - this would never be false.  Please include your full query.

Comment: THEN "dbo.WF_InstanceSteps.DateCompleted" ELSE    this should be without double quotation  -->     THEN DateCompleted ELSE

Comment: Corrected two mistakes. Empty string used as NULL and double-quote wrapping.

Comment: Rather than the CASE statement you can simply use COALESCE to achieve the same functionality and it will probably be easier to maintain and clearer.
Also, has your issue now changed? The title of the question (invalid column name) doesn't seem to match the actual question (problems with string to date/time conversion)

Comment: So, now you've changed the nature of your question *and* invalidated an answer that's already been given. That's not the way things should work on SO. If your original question is answered by an answer, it's far more polite to accept an answer and then to ask a new one about a new problem. (And the title is still referring to the old question)

Comment: Where does `dbo.WF_Instances` come from? Is this part of an outer query, meaning that you've just pasted a partial subquery?

Comment: Ahh, good to know. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN wi.DateCompleted IS NOT NULL THEN wis.DateCompleted 
        ELSE 'NA' 
    END AS DateCompleted
FROM dbo.WF_Instances AS wi
    INNER JOIN dbo.WF_InstanceSteps AS wis
        ON wi.instance_id = wis.instance_id
WHERE wi.StepId = 6
```